# Stack overflow when I try to build an octree structure

Tags: c++, vector, tree

I want to build an n-dimensional tree. I use a `vector` to store the children of each node. The code I wrote gives "stack overflow error", and I don't know why, I do use `new`. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me where I went wrong.

```
class Node
{
public:
  int q_number;
  int layer;
  int value;
  vector<Node*> n_list;

  Node(int n):q_number(n),n_list(n) //initialize node vector
  {
  }
};

Node* buildtree(int n,int depth)
{
  Node * node = new Node(depth);

  if(n==depth-1)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<depth;i++)
    {
      node->n_list[i] = NULL;
      node->n_list[i]->value = i;
      node->n_list[i]->layer = depth-1;
    }
  }
  else
  { 
    for (int i =0;i<depth;i++)
    {               
      node->n_list[i] = buildtree(n++,depth);// span the tree recursively           
      node->n_list[i]->value = i;
      node->n_list[i]->layer = n;   // the layer value
    }
  }

  return node;
}
int main()
{
  Node * tree = buildtree(0,8); // build an octree
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code in your post.

Comment: I'm wondering if you found this site because of "stack overflow" error? Given that this is your first question it's very possible

Comment: I don't think we should be helping the Dark Lord build an orctree, it's bound to end badly for us humans.

Comment: You're getting "stack overflow" error because of too-deep *recursion*. If you'd use `new` and the problem were with that, you'd probably get an "out of memory" error.

Comment: What call and arguments give you the error?

Comment: "octree", not "orctree". You do know what "orc" is, right?

Comment: Your actual code must have some additional lines at the top, most likely `#include <vector>`, `include <cstddef>`, and `using namespace std;`. If you're going to copy-and-paste your program into your question (which is certainly encouraged), please copy *all* of it.

Answer (score 2):

As [Dolda2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134252/dolda2000) noticed, you are *post-incrementing `n`* when calling `buildtree` recursively. Thus, `n` is incremented *after* its old value (unchanged) has been passed to the function. Thus, you have an infinite stack of `buildtree(0,8);` calls, which naturally results in stack overflow.

*Pre*-incrementing — `buildtree(++n,depth);` — would solve the problem with stack overflow, but that's **not** what you want in this case, since you make use of `n` after the recursive call. As I understand your intention, you do not expect the value of `n` to change after the recursive call.

The solution in your case is just:

```
buildtree(n+1,depth);
```

---

There's another problem in your code:

```
    node->n_list[i] = NULL; // ok, the pointer is NULL now
    node->n_list[i]->value = i; // trying to dereference a NULL pointer => error
    node->n_list[i]->layer = depth-1;
```

You need either a `new Node(...)` here, or change vector's value type from `Node*` to `Node`, ... or make sure the pointer is properly set before dereferencing it.

P.S. And make sure that `n <= depth-1` — by an assertion, or include a comment in code at least to avoid lots of debugging later.

Comment: Yes, you are right, how silly I am.problem solved, thank you very much Alex, thank for your patience, and explanation.

Comment: @CallmeACE: glad ho help :)